# Standardization of Out-of-Time variables using lasso regression

Tags: lasso, standardization, out-of-sample

I need to run Out-Of-Time predicts in LASSO regression.
In Out-Of-Time sample, what should I use to standardize variables? The mean and SD of the Out-Of-Time sample or the mean and SD of the insample data?

Comment: Presumably in your training you did something like $x \to x' = \frac{x-\bar x}{s_x}$ and $y \to y' = \frac{y-\bar y}{s_y}$ with the reverse $\hat y = \hat y' s_y +\bar y$. You should usually use those training $\bar x, s_x, \bar y, s_y$ with your new predictions so that you have the same model

Comment: Thanks, Henry. I understand I should use mean and SD of training. However, I am not standardazing y that is a binary 0 or 1 variable. Should I standardize y too?

Comment: No need - just do in testing precisely what you did in training

Comment: Thank you very much.